# User control event handler subscription

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows forms app with a user control. I'm trying to get the UC to call a function on the main form, but when I add the UC, the main form can't see the public event.

My UC looks like this:

```
public partial class uctlLogin: UserControl
{
    public delegate void ButtonClickedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event ButtonClickedEventHandler OnUserControlButtonClicked;

    public uctlLogin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        btnLogin.Click += new EventHandler(OnButtonClicked);
    }

    private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (OnUserControlButtonClicked != null)
            OnUserControlButtonClicked(this, e);
    }
}
```

My form code is:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    UserControl uctlLogin1 = new TabletUserControls.uctlLogin();

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        uctlLogin1.OnUserControlButtonClicked += new EventHandler(OnUCButtonClicked);
    }

    private void OnUCButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Horray!");
    }

    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(uctlLogin1);

    }
}
```

The problem is in this line:

```
uctlLogin1.OnUserControlButtonClicked += new EventHandler(OnUCButtonClicked);
```

Generates the following message:

> *'System.Windows.Forms.UserControl' does not contain a definition for 'OnUserControlButtonClicked' and no extension method
>   'OnUserControlButtonClicked' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.UserControl' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)*

I've tried putting the UC in the same project and creating the UC in a separate project, then adding a reference to it. After Googling for hours, I'm stuck. Any idea what I'm missing here?

BTW, I'm using VS2012 targeting the .Net Framework 4.5.

Comment: Just a small suggestion - not directly related to your question - you should implement your `OnButtonClicked` event handler like this: `var @event = OnUserControlButtonClicked; if (@event != null) @event(this, e);`. While it may not be an issue in most code in a multi-threaded app it is possible that the delegate becomes null after the null check, but before the call, and this will cause a crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because in your `frmMain`, you declared `uctlLogin1` as `UserControl`, rather than `uctlLogin`. The type `UserControl` doesn't have a `OnUserControlButtonClicked` event, and the compiler doesn't know that `uctlLogin1` is an instance of `uctlLogin`, since you declared it as `UserControl`. Just specify the actual type of `uctlLogin1` and it will work fine.

Comment: Bingo! Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees...
Thanks Thomas.